# Copying clicked row in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, textfield, mouselistener

I am trying to copy one clicked by the user row in JTextArea, but I have no idea as to going about it. I've read the other posts, but I still do not understand how to bring it together to solve my problem.

Comment: hey and welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your question. What a row you mean? Row in table of your application? Row from another text component in your application or something else? Please also add a [mcve] as it was proposed in the post above.

Comment: What does a "clicked row" mean to you. Is it just the row where the caret is displayed? Is it selected text on that row? What don't you understand? Do you know how to use a MouseListener? Do you know how to get the row where the caret is? Do you know how to get the selected text? Do you know how to get the text for the row even if it is not selected? What do you want to do with the text? Add it to the clipboard? Copy it to another component?